# OPC UA [asyncua] CreateSigningRequest (CSR)

Tags: python, opc-ua, csr

I would like to implement the basic GDS (global discovery server) functionality using python https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio.
From what I can see, currently freeopcaua has all methods available for this procedure except CreateSigningRequest https://reference.opcfoundation.org/GDS/v104/docs/7.7.6 . I'm looking for tips on how I can do this myself.

I tried to use https://opcua-asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/asyncua.client.html#asyncua.client.ua_client.UaClient.call but it seems to be wrong way.

Edit 2:
I tried the following code (according to @Schroeder suggestion):

```
client = Client(url=url)
await client.set_security(
    SecurityPolicyBasic256Sha256,
    certificate=r"C:\other\my_cert.der",  # cert,
    private_key=r"C:\other\my_private_key.pem",  # private_key,
)

async with client:
    csr_method = NodeId(ObjectIds.CreateSigningRequestMethodType)
    server_config = client.get_node(ObjectIds.ServerConfiguration)
    args = (
        ua.Variant(
            NodeId(ObjectIds.ServerConfigurationType_CertificateGroups_DefaultApplicationGroup),
            ua.VariantType.NodeId),
        ua.Variant(
            NodeId(ObjectIds.RsaSha256ApplicationCertificateType),
            ua.VariantType.NodeId),
        ua.Variant("", ua.VariantType.String),
        ua.Variant(False, ua.VariantType.Boolean),
        ua.Variant(b"", ua.VariantType.ByteString))
    cert = await server_config.call_method(csr_method, *args)
```

But it results:

```
asyncua.ua.uaerrors._auto.BadMethodInvalid: "The method id does not refer to a method for the specified object."(BadMethodInvalid)
```

Comment: Do you have any return code? Also a code example who you use the call method, would be usefull to check if you pass the correct datatypes.

Comment: Added code to the original question

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the object to the call:

```
client = Client(url=url)
await client.set_security(
    SecurityPolicyBasic256Sha256,
    certificate=r"C:\other\my_cert.der",  # cert,
    private_key=r"C:\other\my_private_key.pem",  # private_key,
)

async with client:
    csr_method = NodeId(ObjectIds.CreateSigningRequestMethodType)
    server_config = client.get_node(ObjectIds.ServerConfiguration)
    args = (...,...,...,...)
    cert = await server_config.call(csr_method, args)
```

Comment: I tried code as you suggested but still I got the same error: (BadMethodInvalid). I updated original question

Comment: Btw How can I find the relation that the parent of "CreateSigningRequestMethodType" is "ServerConfiguration".

Comment: It's in the spec. But also you can use uaexpert to find it out. Also it's a good idea to use uaexpert, to test the method inputs.